Mutation graphql calling from react
When I call from client to server, 400 Error occured.
I completely don't know where should I check.
When I called just "id" then, it works. however,
when I added a more parameter "parentId", it doesn't work.
Any idea?
Apollograhpql (Server)
** schema.gql **
type Mutation {
  updatePackaging(id: String!, parentId: String): Packaging!
}

** ProjectResolver.ts **
@Mutation(() => Packaging)
async updatePackaging(
  @Arg("id") id: string,
  @Arg("parentId", { nullable: true }) parentId: string,
  @Ctx() context: Context
) {
  console.log(`씨발!!! ${id}, ${parentId}`);

  return {
    id,
    parentId,
  };
}

Client (React + ts)
# This works!
export const fetchUpdatePackaging = (packaging: types.Packaging) =>
  http.post<{ updatePackaging: types.Packaging | null }>("/", {
    query: `
      mutation UpdatePackaging($id: String!) {
        updatePackaging(id: $id) {
          id
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: packaging.id,
    },
  });


# This DOSE NOT Works for same API (400 Bad Request). WHY???????
# This just added a more parameter : parentId
export const fetchUpdatePackaging = (packaging: types.Packaging) =>
  http.post<{ updatePackaging: types.Packaging | null }>("/", {
    query: `
      mutation UpdatePackaging($id: String!, $parentId: String) {
        updatePackaging(id: $id, parentId: $parentId) {
          id
          parentId
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: packaging.id,
      parentId: packaging.parentId,
    },
  });



Wild guess: Since parentId nullable, you also need to make sure the return type Packaging also has this present and as a nullable.

Also check server logs, and also response body in dev tools.

Thank you for the reply. Problem was "Packaging" in API. parentId was missing in there.

This is the model "Packaging"
And I found that "parentId" was missed.
Here's so many columns and I missed the columns.
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
import { PackagingComponent } from "./PackagingComponent";

@ObjectType()
export class Packaging {
  @Field()
  id!: string;

  @Field()
  parentId?: string;

  // ... more
}

